Tibco ems to solace using apache camel
Is there a provision to send and receive message from a tibco queue to solace queue using apache camel?
If yes please help how? can we create a route directly .
i tried hybridedge but that is no longer supported. Can you suggest .

Solace has a supported integration for EMS on their Integration Hub which would be the recommended way of doing this unless you have a requirement to use Camel: https://solace.com/integration-hub/pubsub-connector-for-tibco-ems/

do u have the detailed implementation of it on how to do it. I can't find much on this.

also it needs a licence version. our applications need to connect to partner who is on solace and we are on tibco ems so cannot use pubsub +
